# Решение конфликтов в GIT

Tags: git

Всем привет.

Сотрудник модифицировал несколько десятков файлов. Потом попытался обновить проект коммандой git pull и получил кучу конфликтов на эти файлы. Умел решать такие ситуации только командой git checkout --theirs xxx. Для каждого файла забивать команду не стал а не придумал ничего лучше как удалить файлы и попытаться проапдейтить заново. Естественно ничего не получилось. Разные попытки решить проблему успехом не увенчались -- поднимает проект из репозитория заново.

Соотв два вопроса

1. Как правильно было решить ситуацию с множественными конфликтами (файлы из одного каталога) ?
2. Если уж проблема зашла так далеко (файлы удалены) -- как правильно их восстановить ?

Спасибо

Comment: если возникли конфликты - их нужно решать. По другому никак. Я для этих целей использую meld - просто с командой строки запускаю в папке с проектом `meld .` (там точка - текущий каталог) и дальше выбираю, как объединить изменения. Иногда это бывает очень сложно.

Comment: Никак не восстановить. Изменения не сохранились ни в стеше, ни в коммите. Как поступить правильно - работать в отдельной ветке, чтобы не было необходимости пуллить изменения от других. Если без этого никак, то, как вариант, перед пуллом засквошить все коммиты в 1, чтобы затем разрешать конфликт в рамках одного коммита, а не всех.

Comment: Не, ну theirs восстановить можно простым `git checkout -f`

Comment: "восстановить" -- имел в виду скачать версию из репозитория. А так как файлы удалены -- сделать этого git pull -- нельзя. Подробней -- на 3D сцене просчитано освещение. Сотрудник хотел посмотреть как будет выглядеть результат с другими параметрами и пересчитал освещение сам. Изменились десятки файлов. Тем временем второй сотрудник отвечающий за сборку сцены -- пересобрал и закоммитил новую. То-есть первому нужно было проапдейтить из репозитория новые изменения выбросив свои эксперименты.